# How do I assign a variable a number that is in my excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the number in cell "C1" of my spreadsheet used as a variable V = C1. How do I code that? Help me please

```
!   Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
'  I want the number in cell "C1" of my spreadsheet used as a variable V = C1
    i = 2
    v = 7
    k = 3
'
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(v).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways but, to get you started, you can use

`i = ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1").Value`

To assign $C$1 to variable `i`. The worksheet must contain a numeric value in $C$1 for this to work.

In a `Sub` you can also write the value `i` directly to the worksheet:

`ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1").Value = i`

Later on, consider replacing `ActiveSheet` with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<your sheet name>")` and converting the `Sub` to a `Function`.

Comment: why would a Function be better?

Comment: Because then it becomes part of the calculation cycle.

Comment: But functions can't generally modify a worksheet apart from the function return value. A Sub with `ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2").Value = 1` can't be converted to a Function.

Comment: No but it *could* be the return value.